# Examples for Amiga 500 newbie Programmers with the GNU C/C++ Compiler, or with FPC - the Free Pascal Compiler

Tags: amiga

Note: This is a review of me, to get the Focus, on which this Post stand.

My Amiga 500 is dead since 20 decades, but I loved the time with it, so I use the Windows UAE (Ultimate Amiga Emulator).

I'd like to programming a little bit it with the Visual Studio C++ or other GNU C/C++ Tools.

It is hard to do this?
I have no Commodore Assembler skills

But I can code in C/C++.
I know Assembler, but only for x86 Arch.
Can I produce graphical Application with GNU C?
How could I setup FPC, to Compiler Amiga Applications under Windows 10 64bit ?

Can you give me a little example, that open graphical screen, and set a rectangle ?

Thanks for ideas, Jens

Comment: Would this serve as a good starting point? http://www.pjhutchison.org/tutorial/amiga_c.html

See also http://www.guru-meditation.info/FNA/sections/Download/Manuali/Amiga%20C%20For%20Advanced%20Programmers.pdf

Comment: Tools-wise, I'd take a look at https://github.com/bebbo/amiga-gcc

Comment: If you know x86, then 68k shouldn't be hard to pick up.

Comment: thank you all for the welcoming touch to your group/community !

Comment: Do you know what you want to create? Are you going to use the OS or program the hardware directly?

Comment: Sorry - forgot to add: Please also note that programming the C64 will be completely different from programming an Amiga. The Amiga will be more akin to a modern system (multitasking OS with GUI) than the C64. Which one to choose is really down to personal preference.

Comment: hello @Edders, I have much skill in Pascal/Delphi, amd C/C++ as in Assembler, and I am not intended to write hardware directly. This can be a topic, but I am thinking, that too much for me.

Comment: it is a good idea, to write a workbench, new. Is that the OS, or the urloader for all other software? also speaking of firmware? i have skills to write the hardware of a x86 directly in real 16 bit mode - like graphics and keyboard.

Comment: @Jens I don't know of a modern Pascal/Delphi implementation, but there is an older Pascal IDE named "KickPascal", which I used at the time. The Workbench is the name of the desktop GUI, if you make your own GUI programs then you will be calling the functions of OS libraries like "Intuition" and "GadTools".

Comment: my attention in programming are desktop application, and compiler programming. currently, I work on a web platform for database developer in the web browser. so they don't need be angry to have the wrong or missing dll like it is modern in Windows. But my goal is, to provide a universal compiler - like the java bytecode compiler. okay, all that was invented, too. but don't trust a bill, that you ....

Comment: @Edders The Turbo Rascal IDE (https://lemonspawn.com/turbo-rascal-syntax-error-expected-but-begin/) uses Pascal and can target many systems, including the Amiga.